# Can you cast an object to an interface it doesn't explicitly implement?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, interface

I'm specifically interested in implementing a [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) where one (or more) of the strategies come from a third-party library.

I have a third-party library with a class like so:

```
public class LibraryClass {
    public void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I then created my own class with the same interface:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now in my code I want to do the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public interface Strategy {
        void doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Strategy oneClass = (Strategy)(new MyClass());
        Strategy twoClass = (Strategy)(new LibraryClass());
        oneClass.doSomething();
        twoClass.doSomething();
    }
}
```

In this case the method exists, so the interface is ***technically*** valid, but it wasn't explicitly implemented. When I tried doing this, it threw a run-time error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: MyClass cannot be cast to MainActivity$Controls
```

Worst-case scenario I know I can use a [Proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to wrap `LibraryClass` in something that ***does*** implement the `Strategy` interface:

```
public class LibraryClassProxy implements Strategy {
    private LibraryClass internal;
    public void LibraryClassProxy() {
        internal = new LibraryClass();
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        internal.doSomething();
    }
}
```

But I'd prefer to avoid this if possible - in particular because the class I'm extending implements ***a lot of other interfaces***, and I'd rather not have to proxy every single public method.

Comment: Method definition is irrelevant. An object must implement the class/interface to be cast to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, in Java interface definitions are based on explicit declarations. I believe the situation you are describing is covered by the [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) design pattern, not the Proxy:

> **Intent:** Convert the interface of a class into another interface clients expect. Adapter lets classes work together that couldn't otherwise because of incompatible interfaces. ---GoF p. 139

And the "Proxy" solution you point out corresponds to the **object** variant of the Adapter pattern. If `LibraryClass` is not final, one option to consider is to use the **class** variant of the pattern:

```
class MyLibraryClass extends LibraryClass implements Strategy {
   /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Giving this the accepted answer because of the incredibly elegant solution (extending `LibraryClass` so I don't have to re-implement any methods). When I tested it out there was ***one*** small caveat: Java complained that `LibraryClass` had no default constructor (to be honest: I'm not sure how one specifies a "default" constructor) so I had to implement a constructor for `MyLibraryClass` like so: `public MyLibraryClass() { super() }`

Answer (score 1):

From [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html):

> When you define a new interface, you are defining a new reference data
>   type. You can use interface names anywhere you can use any other data
>   type name. If you define a reference variable whose type is an
>   interface, any object you assign to it **must be an instance of a class
>   that implements the interface**.

So, you can't cast an object to an interface that is not explicitly implemented

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is basically a form of [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): You have an interface with a `doSomething` method, and you want to be able to pass off anything with that method as an implementation of that interface, even if it does not explicitly specify that it implements the interface.

You can't do that kind of duck typing in Java; *all* type relationships have to be explicit. But with lambdas and SAM conversion, you can do something that is *pretty* close to that.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public interface Strategy {
        void doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Strategy oneClass = new MyClass()::doSomething;
        Strategy twoClass = new LibraryClass()::doSomething;

        oneClass.doSomething();
        twoClass.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Rather than trying to cast (which you can't), create new `Strategy` objects using the `doSomething` methods of the objects you want. Personally, it feels like a dirty hack, but hey, it's what you wanted.